# How to design a circuit with array of amplifiers?

Tags: amplifier, design, low-noise-amplifier

1. If I have a very tiny signal voltage and I want to amplify it 100 times higher with low noise amplifier, how should I design the circuit? I mean for example how should I know that I need capacitors or resistors or both. How to determine the amount for each resistor?
2. I know this is related to electrical engineering textbooks for circuit design and signal conditioning but I am not electrical engineer and I was wondering if there is a book that already has prepared some circuits for people like me who do not want to design from scratch?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K03Rom3Cs28

Comment: You will need to be more specific to get much joy searching or asking here. The frequency range is really important just to get started- an amplifier for close to DC or for audio frequencies will be quite different from one for VHF or microwave frequencies. Also, your "low noise" requirement needs to be quantified.

Comment: thank you. This is the output of a sensor I am talking about. I just get some signals from the sensor when I apply force on it. that signal is low and mixed with noise what should I do? How do I know the frequency? (no datasheet for the sensor)

Comment: The signal range is -0.04mv to 0.04mv. lost in noise.

Comment: The sensor has no data sheet.

Comment: Frequency 0-50Hz

Comment: Is the sensor a strain gauge like in question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214164/how-to-design-a-circuit-with-array-of-amplifiers ?

Comment: This is *very* closely related to OP's other question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/how-do-you-measure-nano-volt-order-signals/214179#214179 -- maybe a merge is in order?

Answer (score 4):

Beginner electronics.  Searching the internet is your friend. There are so many web sites for beginning electronics.

One place to go  :  http://www.hobbyprojects.com/

[Click this for another site](http://www.electroschematics.com/)

With amplifiers, the word GAIN is used to describe how much more the output signal is compared to the input signal.  You could search for "amplifier gain 100".

EDIT : To other commentors and other answers, Try to use Key Words in answers and comments, so that other newbies could find this question more easily on a search.

Comment: Thank you pal but I am not talking about the audio. I am talking about sensor and instrumentation. This is not a hobby project I am doing! Most of the stuff out there are for audio applications or my search results are usually tend to how design the amplifier itself rather than using it in the circuit!

Comment: @Silas "pal" is disrespectful. Remember you're the one asking for help here.

Comment: I meant friend. I did not mean anything bad!! Why everyone in here very judgmental! In one comment they call the question "newbie" and then no single satisfactory answer is given with you experts!!

Comment: No satisfactory answer has been given because no satisfactory question was asked. Welcome to SE, Silas. There are quite a few of us who spend a lot of time helping people here but get fed up with people asking bad questions and expecting us to guess what the application is. Put the information in your first comment into your question. Explain what the sensor is. Instead of words like '_tiny signal_' use measurements like '5 mV peak to peak at 1 kHz' or 'slowly varying air pressure sensor signal ranging from 0.1 V at sea-level to 0.377 V at 3,000 m'. Do you get the idea?

Comment: @transistor First of all I am really thankful of all of you. secondly I noticed if I explain more you will put it on hold and say too many questions and If I do not explain you will say it is too general and not enough information. The question is question. If people do not have time to answer simply do not. If people need more specifications and details in the question simply ask it and I try to respond.

Comment: The sensor has no data sheet used to measure micro newton forces.

Comment: The signal range is -0.04mv to 0.04mv. lost in noise.

Comment: Frequency 0-50Hz

Comment: OK. So put all that information neatly **into the original question**. It was all relevant and required for anybody to answer it in the first place. If you improve the question we can get it taken off hold.

Comment: @Silas: I see you've [asked the question again](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/how-do-you-measure-nano-volt-order-signals) rather than fix this one. This is a bit disrespectful for those of us who have put some effort in to helping you. It's still a poor question judging by the number of clarifications that had to be asked in the comments.